# teradata xml services on IBM z/os

Tags: xml, teradata, zos

can you extract data from teradata on ibm z/os as an XML document?
i have searched and found Teradata XML services on windows, unix, etc but it doesnt appear to be available on IBM Mainframe.
are there any other options to extract data from Teradata as a complete xml document?

Comment: One thing to always keep in mind is that z/OS UNIX System Services is UNIX. So if it is supposed to work in UNIX, then it is supposed to work in USS. However, keep an eye out for code that assumes ASCII.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It [looks like](http://downloads.teradata.com/download/connectivity/jdbc-driver) there's a JDBC driver that will run in z/OS Unix System Services.